# Как реализовать такой графический интерфейс на canvas?

Tags: html, css, canvas

Ребята всем привет есть задача:
Нужно создать 2 экрана на canvas один вид сверху, другой перспектива.
На виде сверху можно сделать разные фигуры:
параллелепипед
цилиндр
полусфера
Также на виде сверху существую слои.
А на перспективе просто первый экран показывается в 3d.
Так вот я думаю что только canvas с таким функционалом не справится, может подскажете что где потыкать, посмотреть, если кто сталкивался с таким, спасибо!

Также нужно организовать функции пермещения, вращения и масштабирования:
Я выбрал более менее 2 изветных библиотеки это paper.js и jcanvas?
Знает кто-нибудь потянут ли они на такой функционал?

Comment: Для отображения в 3д, и чтоб можно было поворачивать фигуры нужно использовать WebGL, к примеру [Babylon JS](http://www.babylonjs-playground.com/) или [Three.js](https://habrahabr.ru/post/224509/), а canvas может отрисовывать только 2д изображения. В одном из проектов использовал так: на canvas размещались фигуры в 2д режиме, а на Babylon JS отрисовывались они же, но уже в 3д, при этом использовался один и тот же JSON объект для отрисовки (в моем случае заборы).

Comment: А какую библиотеку вы использовали для отрисовки 2d?
Знаете ли вы про paper.js может ли он справится с таким функционалом?

Comment: @MrFylypenko вовсе не обязятельно рисовать трёхмерные объекты только с помощью webGL и библиотек по типу three.js ит.д.. webGL и 2D context API от HTML5 - это всего лишь иструменты для растеризации примитивов на плоскости. Спокойно можно на том же двухмерном канвасе спроецировать трёхмерные объекты. нужно лишь уметь правильно спроецировать 3D точки в 2D при помощи например, матричных преобразований

Comment: У нас использовался AngularJS + [EaselJS](http://www.createjs.com/easeljs),  скрещивал их не я ((, но все работает. Про paper.js и jcanvas не слышал, спасибо за наводку. Нарисовать фигуры на любой canvas библиотеке будет не сложно, вот правда со слоями придется повозиться для отображения с 2 ракурсов.

Comment: про слои очень согласен, сейчас на пути к пониманию этого =/